# how to use search widget in custom listview with sqlite in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-widget

I have a custom listView with custom adapter, there are name, designation and some other information. I want to use search(widget) option in that please help me. Here is my adapter code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.Image;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Imran on 10/25/2015.
 */
public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ContactModel> {

    private ArrayList<ContactModel> contactList;
    private ContactModel contactModel;
    Context context;
    TextView name;
    TextView company;
    TextView designation;
    TextView phoneNo;
    TextView email;
    ImageView image;

    public ContactAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ContactModel> contactList) {
        super(context, R.layout.customlayout,contactList);
        this.context=context;
        this.contactList=contactList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.customlayout,parent,false);


        image= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageId);

        name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNameId);
        company=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCompanyId);
        designation=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesignationId);
        phoneNo=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPhoneNoId);
        email=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmailId);

        contactModel=contactList.get(position);
        name.setText(contactModel.getName());
        company.setText(contactModel.getCompanyName());
        designation.setText(contactModel.getDesignation());
        phoneNo.setText(contactModel.getPhoneNo());
        email.setText(contactModel.getEmail());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I have searched online much but there is no solution like what i want. so please help me. waiting for your kind help. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Visit this post , Here is the same case as you want . Modify it according to your's

[Android Search Filter ListView](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-filter-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/)